# One codebase for 2 versions

Tags: actionscript-3, structure, directory-structure

I am making a project in AS3, but I have come to a point, where I need to branch out, because I want it to publish to 2 places, which each require a bit of different additional code to function properly. So is it possible to achieve that I do not need to make 2 projects and maintain 2 similar projects?

I hope I wrote it clear enough.
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: you can use "conditional compilation" - heres an example of use for flash pro: http://www.richnetapps.com/flash-cs4-supports-conditional-compilati/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do several things, depending on whether you're working in the Flash IDE, Flash Builder, or one of the other tools like IntelliJ.

If you are working in the Flash IDE and/or have a Flash Professional project set up in Flash Builder, you can go into the ActionScript Properties panel and set up a source path that points anywhere (I usually try to keep it relative, but it's up to you).

If you're working without a fla/xfl, then you probably need to look at setting up a [library project](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fe6.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a big reaseon for **OOP**! Write Base Classes and extend them for your Projects as needed.

Also check out [Conditional Compilation](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=257)